# PHP save array from json(GSON) in db

Tags: php, android, arrays, json

in PHP I would like to save the data from a string that comes from Android in a database.
The string of data that arrives is in the following format:

```
[{"Field":"1","Field2":"2","Field3":"3"},
 {"Field":"4","Field2":"5","Field3":"6"},
 {"Field":"7","Field2":"8","Field3":"9"}]
```

I searched around and many recommend using json_decode so I try this code:

```
<?php
$jsonData = '[{"Field1":"1", "Field2":"2", "Field3":"3"},
              {"Field1":"4", "Field2":"5", "Field3":"6"},
              {"Field1":"7", "Field2":"8", "Field3":"9"}]';
$phpArray = json_decode($jsonData);
print_r($phpArray);
```

and the result is this:

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [Field1] => 1 [Field2] => 2 [Field3] => 3 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [Field1] => 4 [Field2] => 5 [Field3] => 6 ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [Field1] => 7 [Field2] => 8 [Field3] => 9 ) )
```

But I would not know how to continue with store in db.
Someone could help me? thank

Comment: How you want to store in database? Whole string or array values in different fields ?

Comment: What don't you know? How iterate array? How you must write inserts to db? You need provide more infos.

Comment: It might be easier for you to have an associative output:  `json_decode($jsonData, true)`

Comment: I would like to save various records in the table, in the appropriate fields.
For exemple I already have the table "table1" with fields "Field1","Field2","Field3".
With a "insert to" I would like to enter the third record of the example above
Sorry for my English...